# Can i open the "details pane" when i click on the Title

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-form

I have a sharepoint online custom list >> and i have customized the list forms using PowerApp >> now when i click on the item Title field >> i will be redirected to the powerapp form >> instead can i force the click on the Title field to open the item's Details Pane >> similar effect as when we click on the Details item menu, as follow:-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In a modern SharePoint list, you can turn on the details pane by clicking the "i" in a circle at the top right of the active screen. When no item is selected, the pane shows info about the list. If an item is selected (by clicking the row of an item or ticking the circle in the leftmost column of the list view), the details show on the pane.

If the item is double clicked or the Title field is clicked, the item will open in the PowerApps form if it is configured.

However, in the Advanced Settings of the list, there is an option to prevent editing list items via the Details pane (or via Quick Edit). When the PowerApps form is used to govern field settings with logic rules, it often makes sense to prevent edits via the details pane.

Comment: thanks for the valuable info , i actually want to show the Details Pane so the users can view all the item info, as some of the fields are not shown inside the power app..so can i force the Title click to open the Details Pane